# Get linked database property relation when retrieving database with Notion API

Tags: notion-api

When retrieving a database (/v1/databases/:id), the relation properties don't show up.

- I have made sure to add my integration to both databases
- Other properties of my primary database are returned

Perhaps it's me who doesn't understand the documentation [here](https://developers.notion.com/reference/retrieve-a-database#additional-resources). I thought that if I added the integeration to my linked database, the properties from my primary database who refer to the linked database would be included.